# Ticks and labels removed on only SOME of the subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot, subplot

I want to have boxplots (horisontal) with only ticks and labels along the x axis. However, when the loop reached axis = 12, it adds ticks and labels to the y axis, even though it was removed from axis=1 to axis=11.

Why does this happen? See picture of behaviour below.
[image]

**Code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
fig,axs = plt.subplots(12,3,figsize=(15,50),dpi=200)
fig.suptitle("Box plot for all 34 features",fontsize=16)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.96)

i=1
for column in undersampled_data:

    if (column == 'TimeStamp' or column == 'Status'):
        continue
    ax = fig.add_subplot(12,3,i)
    ax.set_title(column)
    sns.boxplot(undersampled_data[column],palette="Set2")
    ax.set_xlabel('')

    # Removing y ticks and y labels
    frame1 = plt.gca()
    frame1.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    frame1.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])

    print(i ," ",column)
    i+=1

for j in range(0,(len(axs)-1)):
    fig.delaxes(axs.flatten()[j])

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4)
```

Comment: Considering you already defined the plots in the command, fig,axs = ....  i'm not sure why you would add them again in the loop. Also you already have the element ax, so I think there is no need to use plt.gca to get them again

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem, but I don't know exactly what is causing this issue. It might be related to the redefinition of the axis of the figure. If you use `plt.subplots` you should not call `fig.add_subplot` later, but use the stored axis objects. You might start from this simplified example:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(12,3,figsize=(15,50),dpi=200)
axs = axs.flatten() # convert from (12, 3) to (36,)
fig.suptitle("Box plot for all 34 features",fontsize=16)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.96)

for i in range(36):
    axs[i].set_title('test')
    axs[i].plot([1], [1], 'ro')
    axs[i].set_xlabel('')

    axs[i].yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    axs[i].yaxis.set_ticks([])

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4)
```